# Olympic National Park Rain Forest in April

Tags: usa, national-parks

The visitor center at Hoh is weekend-only until June. Is this because the forest is no fun or hard to walk in, or because not very many people show up? I will be close enough to consider a trip in late April.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that it is mostly due to the fewer people, as [there are multiple visitor centers throughout the park](http://www.nps.gov/olym/planyourvisit/visitorcenters.htm), some open every day. However, [in the winter season, it rains a lot](http://www.nps.gov/olym/planyourvisit/visiting-the-hoh.htm) in the forest so this is less comfortable. As it is still open on weekends, it is not impracticable, just less popular.

If you visit in the lower season, be careful [as some roads may be closed and weather can be a problem](http://www.nps.gov/olym/planyourvisit/hours.htm). Make sure you check [the current conditions](http://www.nps.gov/olym/planyourvisit/current-conditions.htm) before visiting the park.